# Select Automatically from Item List

Tags: android, list, select, android-arrayadapter

I have one class that shows me a list of Items. Right now I am selecting this items with click (setOnItemClickListener), but i don't want that. What i want is: when i open the class automatically is selecting the last item on the list.

Can anyone tell me how I can do it?

Thanks for any help

```
public class SelectCodIncidence extends Activity {

private ArrayList<String> datos;
protected netAppApplication app;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.codincidence);
    datos = new ArrayList<String>();
    //datosCod = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        NotesCenter messageCenter = new NotesCenterImpl();

        List<CodIncidence> codincidence = messageCenter.getCodIncidence();                                      
        for (CodIncidence e : codincidence) {
            //datosCod.add("1");
            datos.add(e.id);

        }   
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        //  showMessage(ex);
            Log.v("blah", ex.getMessage());


        }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = 
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datos);     

    final TextView lblMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.MensajeCodIncidence);       
    final GridView grdOptions = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.GridCodIncidence);
    grdOptions.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, android.view.View v, int position, long id) {        

            CodIncidence codincidenceSelected = new CodIncidence();
            codincidenceSelected.id = datos.get(position);
            app = (netAppApplication)getApplicationContext();
            app.setcodincidenceActual(codincidenceSelected);
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("netAppSetup",2);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("CODINCIDENCE", codincidenceSelected.id);
            editor.commit();
            finish();
        }
    });

    grdOptions.setAdapter(adaptador);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
int count = spinner.getCount();
if (count > 0){
    spinner.setSelection(count-1,true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was trying to adapt that code in to my code but it gives me a lot of errors. Could you help me with adapting that code in to my code? Thanks

Comment: In your case, replace Spinner with GridView and spinner should be your grdOptions.